# Check when a process was launched on OS X

Tags: macos, process, time

Activity Monitor lists how much CPU time a process has used over its lifetime, but is there a way to find out the date and time a process was started?

I'm curious because my Firefox hasn't updated for about a month because it hasn't been restarted. My machine uptime is about a month.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ps -o etime`:

```
$ ps -o etime $(pgrep -x Finder)
    ELAPSED
01-22:18:51
$ ps -axco etime,command | grep Finder
01-22:19:00 Finder
```

`01-` = 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do math when using `etime` to subtract that elapsed time from the current date/time, you can use `lstart` instead.

From `man ps`:

```
lstart    The exact time the command started, using the ‘%c’ format described in strftime(3).
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, `ps -f <pid>` seems to do the trick, although it only shows the date and not the time for an old process. There's probably an arcane flag to make the column wider.